# Retrieving from database to display as line graph

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jfreechart

I am trying to display my data from my database. I am currently doing one query execution at a time to get one particular result for each year. I need to do this for all the columns in my database however this will make the code incredibly messy. Is there an easier way to read the data in from the database to display to a line graph?

Current code snippet:

```
DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

String sql = "SELECT SUM(all_motor_vehicles), Year FROM Vehicle WHERE Year = 2005";
pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
rs = pst.executeQuery();
amount = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1)); //get the result
yearFromDB = rs.getString(2);
System.out.println(amount + " " + yearFromDB); //print result


int amount2006;
String yearFromDB2006;
String sql2 = "SELECT SUM(all_motor_vehicles), Year FROM Vehicle WHERE Year = 2006";
pst = con.prepareStatement(sql2);
rs = pst.executeQuery();
amount2006 = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1)); //get the result
yearFromDB2006 = rs.getString(2);
System.out.println(amount2006 + " " + yearFromDB2006); //print result

int amount2007;
String yearFromDB2007;
String sql3 = "SELECT SUM(all_motor_vehicles), Year FROM Vehicle WHERE Year = 2007";
pst = con.prepareStatement(sql3);
rs = pst.executeQuery();
amount2007 = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1)); //get the result
yearFromDB2007 = rs.getString(2);
System.out.println(amount2007 + " " + yearFromDB2007); //print result

dataset.addValue(amount, allMotorVehicles, yearFromDB);
dataset.addValue(amount2006, allMotorVehicles, yearFromDB2006);
dataset.addValue(amount2007, allMotorVehicles, yearFromDB2007);

JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart("Traffic by Vehicle type", "Vehicle", `"Amount",dataset);`
```

Snippet of information in database:

[image]

Implementing suggested Query giving SQL Error:

Executing query in DB returns:

[image]

I can retrieve the year 2005 using rs.getString(1) and it's corresponding number using rs.getString(2) but when I try to retrieve year 2006 and it's number through rs.getString(3) and rs.getString(4) I get an SQLException Error

```
String sql = "SELECT Year, SUM(all_motor_vehicles) AS allmotor\n" +
          

"FROM Vehicle\n"
            + "WHERE Year IN (2005, 2006, 2007)\n"
            + "GROUP BY YEAR;";
    pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();

    amount = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(2)); //retrieves amount
    yearFromDB = rs.getString(1);
    System.out.println(amount + " " + yearFromDB); //retrieves year (2005)
    
    System.out.println(rs.getString(3) + " " + rs.getString(4)); //gives me an SQL ERROR
```

Comment: Your query only has 2 columns in the result set, hence `rs.getString(3)` or `rs.getString(4)` will throw an error.  Consider using the query I gave below in my answer.

Comment: I have implemented your SQL query. How could I retrieve the data from the second & third column?

Comment: You don't, because you only selected _two_ columns.

Comment: I'm confused. If rs.getString(1) and rs.getString(2) retrieve the year 2005 and the number, how could I retrieve the year 2006 and 2007 and their number?

Comment: I have answered your question.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You should instead do a single `GROUP BY` query in which you aggregate sales by year:

```sql
SELECT Year, SUM(all_motor_vehicles) AS all_sales
FROM Vehicle
WHERE Year IN (2005, 2006, 2007)  -- or whatever years you want in your report
GROUP BY Year;
```

I won't bother giving you boilerplate JDBC code for the above query, as you seem to already have the basics of that mastered.  Note that I give an alias to the `SUM()`, in case you would want to access the result set in Java using it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have tried this on my database and it's what I am looking for however, when trying to retrieve the other years other than 2005, I get an SQL Exception error. I have updated the code in the post above with the query you suggested and where the error is happening. Would you mind pointing out where I am going wrong?

Comment: Your comment does not make much sense and would be totally unexpected to me.  Simply _asking_ for any year should not cause an exception, rather it might just mean that don't get any records back.  You should update your question with the exact you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I have updated the post. Sorry it if was unclear before